# Snippets not suggested when typed ahead of word in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In a previous VS code version, if I had an object definition such as

`page 1 abc`

and I started typing one of my snippets (in this case tcopystr)

`tcopystrpage 1 abc`

I would receive my snippet suggestion and be able to complete. Now I need a separator: a new line, comment, or a space for the suggestion to pop up. This is likely because some new setting exists, however I haven't been able to find this setting documented anywhere, or in the settings (using suggestion, intellisense, and snippets to search).

**I am hoping there is some way to revert this behaviour so suggestions ignore the characters past the cursor.**

Here it is in an older vs code version:

https://i.imgur.com/eJXZ1pT.gif

Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Here it is in the current vs code version:

https://i.imgur.com/2zjqdaj.gif

Version: 1.87.2 (system setup)
Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
Electron: 27.3.2
ElectronBuildId: 26836302
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045